# REMIX: ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'payable' address payable target

Tags: solidity, tokens, remix, etherscan

Hello i have the follow contract:

https://pastebin.com/dQJY55hs

I want add this code tu the code above:

```
    constructor(uint _totalSupply) public {
    totalSupply = _totalSupply;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
}

// your standard token transfer function with the addition of the share that
// goes to your target address
function transfer(address _to, uint amount) public {

    // calculate the share for your target address
    uint shareForX = amount/100;

    // store the previous balance of the sender for later assertion
    // (check that all works as intended)
    uint senderBalance = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    // check the sender actually has enough tokens to send
    require(senderBalance >= amount);
    // reduce sender balance first to avoid that the sender sends more than
    // he owns by submitting multiple transactions.
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
    // store the previous balance of the receiver for later assertion
    // (check that all works as intended)
    uint receiverBalance = balanceOf[_to];

    // add the amount of tokens to the receiver but deduce the share for your
    // target address
    balanceOf[_to] += amount-shareForX;
    // add the share to your target address
    balanceOf[target] += shareForX;

    // check that everything works as intended, specifically checking that
    // the sum of tokens in all reladed accounts is the same before and after
    // the transaction. 
    assert(balanceOf[msg.sender] + balanceOf[_to] + shareForX ==
        senderBalance + receiverBalance);
```

}

The problem is i dont know whats wrong but i receive this error in REMIX:

```
browser/savingcoin.sol:79:13: ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'payable'
address payable target = 0x158de12EE547EAe06Cbdb200A017aCa6B75D230D;
        ^-----^
```

This code just send 1% of tokes to X address so i dont know whats wring so please help to me.

Thanks

Comment: This piece of code that shows the error is not in your code, I think you are confusing files, in any case `address payable` is not available in 4.25 but ^5.0, you may want to check that

Answer (score 2):

The `payable` modifier for address types is not available in Solidity until 0.5.0. Either remove the payable modifier, or upgrade your contracts to use Solidity v0.5.0.